# IN Clause - listing values VS query

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, query-performance

My app runs a lot of queries like this

```
SELECT ... FROM Table
    WHERE CategoryID IN (SELECT CategoryID FROM OtherTable WHERE ..)
```

To save performance I decided to cache the second subquery in the application's memory (it rarely changes) and change the DB-query to

```
SELECT ... FROM Table
    WHERE CategoryID IN (123,234,345,456,567,678,789,...)
```

Question: does this make any sense?

PROS: it caches the data which is a good thing. Right?

CONS: the second query cannot be parameterized, so the execution plan is not compiled/cached by the SQL server. Also, the IN clause is treated like a dozen OR's, can this degrade performance?

CategoryID field  in `Table` is an integer with an index.

PS. I tried testing, but I cannot get my tests to the scale of my app (that runs 1000s of queries) so I'd sppreciate any "generic" explanation from someone... Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a join? Something like: `SELECT ... FROM Table as t JOIN OtherTable o ON t.CategoryID = o.CategoryID WHERE ...`

Comment: @Lennart yes, the execution plan generated is nearly identical as with a subquery

Comment: What about the IN clause when the query has a large number of elements?

Comment: @Vérace thats what I'm asking :)

Comment: And I was asking about your execution plan in this scenario? :-)

Comment: IIRC the optimiser under counts very long IN lists so, say, 50 constants may produce an estimated row count of 40. This *may* throw plans off, maybe not. YMMV.

Comment: Consider caching list of IDs in a local #temp table or global ##temp table or normal dedicated table. Thus you can at least avoid transferring this list of IDs from the server to the client and back over the network.Temp tables can have indexes and unique constraints, you can join to them, so it is easier for optimizer to generate a good plan. In any case, you have to figure out how to measure the performance that makes sense for your load and compare different variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after experimenting a bit further with queries and a `set statistics time on`, here's what I found:

**On a small IN-list (4-12 items) - ALMOST identical**

The performance is almost identical, the hardcoded variant uses a little bit more CPU, the overall "elapsed time" is either same or a little bit longer.

**On a bigger IN-list (150+ items) - subquery wins BY FAR**

"CPU-time" is almost 2x shorter, overall "elapsed time" shorter as well.

**Conclusion**

At least on my config I will stick to subquery, not only it is faster, but it allows plan caching.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of this depends on what else your query is doing. If that predicate is one of many, and isn't particularly useful for an index, then you may be seeing that predicate in a Predicate property (being a residual predicate) in your plan.

Alternatively, if you have an index on CategoryID, then are you wanting it to do dozens of Seeks into Table?

I suspect that the cost of the sub-query, especially if it's run frequently so that it's in memory already, would be negligible if you're doing dozens of Seeks. But without an index on CategoryID, you might be better off with just a residual, by using your IN clause. If you have a maximum number of values that could be used, you could parameterise it, like: `(@p1, @p2, ...)`. To get the same number of parameters each time would be important. If you always have between 10 and 15, then maybe code up for 15, and use -1 as the value for any extras (ie, if you have 11 values, then 12-15 could be all -1 to avoid recompilation).

Answer (score 0):

I understand your basic reasoning for hard-coding the list of integers.  However, by changing to a static list of numbers, the query is not as easily maintainable.  If your CategoryID / OtherTable doesn't often change, then this may be acceptable in your situation.

Is "OtherTable" a code (lookup) table by chance?  If so, then having sub-queries perform look ups has worked well, in my experience.  It makes the code more maintainable as you only need to maintain the lookup table as you add/edit/delete categories.